# Rating Articles - Sentiment Analysis

Tags: java, algorithm, math, probability, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a Java program(classifier) which reads a given text file and outputs the related sentiment (Positive or Negative or Neutral).

The program calculates three probabilities for the three classes (Positive or Negative or Neutral). Given these three probabilities i would like give a score(max 10) to the article.

**Example** - 
If suppose,

```
P(Positive) = 0.0006
P(Negative) = 0.0001
P(Neutral)  = 0.0002
```

Then clearly it is evident that the article is highly Positive, hence the rating should be high ie 8 or above.

PS - The probabilities do not add up to 1 and are very very small numbers                         (in the range of ~ 10^-(100))

Could someone point out any algorithm which could help me rate the articles ?

Thanks

---

**EDIT**
I cannot simply take ratios. For example

```
P(Positive) = 1.2*E(-117)
P(Negative) = 4.7*E(-112)
P(Neutral)  = 9.3*E(-110)
```

The probabilities shown above vary hugely. Taking ratios would thus be meaningless.

Comment: I don't think this is really programming related. Should better be at stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks @leonbloy . I am new to StackOverflow, will post this question at stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If {positive, negative, neutral} is the sample space, then strictly speaking you're not dealing with a probability measure here since their P(x) don't sum to 1; this may seem irrelevant here and probably is (so you obviously can ignore this if it is irrelevant), but depending on what you do with those values of P, you may run into trouble if you assume P is a probability measure.

Comment: @G.Bach
you are correct, these are likelihoods of each classes. I was loosely referring them as probabilities. If you go through some research papers related to Sentiment Analysis, you'd find that these probabilities can never add up to 1. This would mean that there could be another class ie - "Unclassified" for docs which fall in none of the other classes.

Since we just want an estimate of what class the doc could possibly belong to we may neglect the other class and choose the most appropriate amongst the three.

PS - I am using Machine Learning to train the classifier.
Anyways Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I did something similar on Amazon comments about 6 months ago (the ground truth for estimating accuracy was the stars rating).

You can use the [**Bag of Words model**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) for this task - i.e. each 'word' is a feature. This causes a problem with very high dimensionality - which might affect the learning time.

After you extract your features from the raw data, you can use one of the [**classification algorithms**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) that are descent with high dimensional problems. I tested [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) (linear and gaussian kernels) and [Naive-Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier). I found SVM scored much better - without statistical significance between the two kernels when I tested on Amazon.

I used nominal classifier with 3 possible values (classes) for my learning algorithms - pro/neutral/against.

I also found that using [feature selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) (to reduce the dimensionality) was extremely helpful for Naive-Bayes but not so much for SVM.

---

**Some more important notes:**

1. Stemming words also helps.
2. Using bi-grams (pairs of words) in addition to words also helps (though increases the dimensionality of the problem even further).
3. For the task I used [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) and [lib-svm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) libraries to implement the
   learning algorithms.
4. I suggest splitting the data for test and train for estimating accuracy of the data, and using [cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) for finding parameters for the algorithms (for example, the parameters needed for SVM)

---

My results: Using SVM, we recieved accuracy of 85% for positive comments and ~80% for negative comments. The real problem was neutrals, we got 70% for it, and the mistakes for pro and against were also mostly because the classifier classified it as "neutral", almost none (less then 5%) were classified as pro/against while they were the exact opposite.

Comment: Thanks amit ! 
I am working with Naive Bayes for some reasons. Our projects seem similar. **But one thing additional which i have to do is generate a rating rather than testing the given rating (as in your case).**


Using the bag of words model i can simplify the representation of documents but **how do i use it to generate a score out of 10 ?**


Do you know of any such algorithm helpful in generating the rating/score given the probabilities of the 3 classes ?

Comment: @AnkitRustagi I used *[supervised learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning)*. In supervised learning you need to have an initial train data, and use it to generate the classifier (this is called the learning process). Usually you will need a few thousands of samples for a learning in this model (rule of thumb). One thing that is sometimes done is outsource this task, spread it to chunks of 10 (example) and let people classify the sentiment for you for the train data (for a fee of course).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Naive Bayes, at some point you calculate a probability (or log liklihood) that a given example is in some class, in your case negative, positive or neutral.  Perhaps you could just multiply that probability times 10 to get your rating?

Comment: Thanks @justin !
Actually the probabilities that i get are very small numbers. This is may be because i have trained my classifier with about **~100** articles. I found that each class approximately had 30,000 words (not unique). Thus due to large no of unique words, the likelihood i get is usually in the range of **~10^(-100)**.

So simply multiplying with 10 wont work here !